# Is it better to write/include OOP in functions.php file of WordPress Custom Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

In creating custom theme in WordPress, there is an optional file you can create by naming it to functions.php file.

I discover that I can write/include OOP code here instead of writing procedural code.

Is it better to write/include the code in OOP for custom theme or should it be the old-way ... the procedural?

Comment: You can write code in functions.php file

Comment: [opinion] I find it kinda sad that in 2016 this is even a question. WordPress is the only major application I know of that still uses procedural code, and it really makes it look old and clunky. My answer: Use OOP wherever possible; use procedural code only where you have to. Better yet, switch to a better CMS platform like Joomla or ModX or Craft or October (or many others), and you'll never have to write procedural code again. Personally I just don't get how WP has managed to keep going so long without modernising.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a big topic.
The direct answer to your question **It all comes down to personal preference of structure.**

**My personal favorite.**

In *functions.php* only have `add_action` and `add_filter`
Then have a *includes* folder with php class files.
Which I include in the *functions.php*.
This way I can keep my *functions.php* clean and readable while all the logic goes into classes.

**The "official" way**

If you check out the default themes *twentyseventeen*, *twentyfifteen* and so on.
They have an *inc* folder and have procedural functions spread out in those and the normal *functions.php* and have the  `add_action`, `add_filter` are right after the function definitions.